# instruments xcode4 not working?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode4, instruments

Im following Ray Wenderlich  [tutorial for instruments](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial), but I don't know why the profiling is not showing the leaked object??

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString * sushiName = [_sushiTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString * sushiString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d: %@", indexPath.row, sushiName];

NSString * message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last sushi: %@.  Cur sushi: %@", _lastSushiSelected, sushiString];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sushi Power!" 
                                                    message:message 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alertView show];

//_lastSushiSelected = sushiString; //el que jode, pues lo pone en string deallocada, por strinWithFormat que usa autorelease!
_lastSushiSelected = [sushiString retain];

//[alertView release];
}
```

Im using the code in the tutorial, and as you can see the alertView is leaking!

But I run it trough instruments leaks, and nothing appears! [also is very very very slow to acknowledge the stop button was pressed to stop the profiling!]

[image: Leaks not detected]

So what is missing??,

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I think it's a bug.  Hopefully it'll be fixed soon (I'm using v4.1) but all is not lost.  Under the Allocations instrument you can filter which types are displayed.  In this image I've told it to show UIAlertView instances.  After clicking in the UITableView a couple of times you can see it tells me that there are 2 instances living, which confirms that there is a leak.

[image]

Comment: Ive had a few bugs in instruments in xcode 4.2. One Im getting a lot is the programme just becomes unresponsive and keeps running; I end up using a Force Quit.

Comment: yeah, i've seen that in 4.1 too.

Comment: and Xcode 3.x as well ... I have taken the habit now of creating class statics to count totalNumberAllocated, and remainingInstances, along with a macro to log that (or not) in the dealloc method, as a function of the debug level i set as a compile switch. Much faster to track those.